# Can I get vim to indent correctly after a here document?

Tags: bash, indentation

In an account with just an emtpy .vimrc, under Xubuntu 20.04 and vim 8.1, I get strange indentaion after my here document if I reindent with gg=G

I've boiled down an example from some pretty tangled code; never mind what it does, this is
about what it looks like.  I added a modeline so you know the basics of how things are set up.

Original code indented as I think correct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim:et:ai:sr:nosi:ts=2:sts=2:sw=2:filetype=bash

if true ; then
  #show 3 words
  for word in one two three
  do
    if true ; then
      cat <<EOF
$word
EOF
      text="You should see 3 lines above"
      echo $text
    fi
  done
fi
```

After doing `gg=G` it looks like this.  The two lines after the here document are shifted to the left margin; in the original this went on for many lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim:et:ai:sr:nosi:ts=2:sts=2:sw=2:filetype=bash

if true ; then
  #show 3 words
  for word in one two three
  do
    if true ; then
      cat <<EOF
$word
EOF
text="You should see 3 lines above"
echo $text
    fi
  done
fi
```

Comment: Short answer: vim’s indentation is not perfect, and some situations are harder than others

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes the hard stuff is worth doing, or at least asking about.